# How to align text to go back a screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement the buttonContainer "Login" in the left hand of the title. I just can not figure this out. When I run it on the emulator and click on the register screen . I can not see Login on the far left. Tried numerous ways to do it with no avail. I'm just unsure how to fix this problem. Could do with some help, thank you.

\\

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import {Button, Input, Image} from "react-native-elements";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from "react-native";

const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const signIn = () => {

    }

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar style="light" />
        <Image
            source={{
                uri:
                "https://blog.mozilla.org/internetcitizen/files/2018/08/signal-logo.png",
            }}
            style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
            />
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Input 
                  placeholder="Email" 
                  autoFocus 
                  type="email" 
                  value={email}
                  onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}    
                  />
                <Input 
                placeholder="Password"
                secureTextEntry
                type="password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                />

            </View>
            <Button containerStyle={styles.button} onPress={signIn} title="Login"  />
            <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")} containerStyle={styles.button} type="outline" title="Register" />
            <View style={{ height: 80 }} />


        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
};

export default LoginScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    inputContainer: {
        width: 300,
    },
    button: {
        width: 200,
        marginTop: 10,
    },
});
```

\\

Comment: Hey did you mean on the top on the left hand of the screen title ? If yes, we are talking about "HeaderButtons".

Comment: Yes, I'm really just unsure how to implement it. I actually thought it was done with the button container

Comment: Okay, wich version of react-navigation you are use ? 4, 5 or 6 ? (You can figure it out in your package.json in your root folder.)

Comment: I'm using: "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
                "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",

Comment: I've continued on with the  with tutorial, but now it using the useLayoutEffect and setting the headerBackTitle there, but mine will not either way

Comment: You also can take a look at the react-navigation documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons 

There is also a snack example ...

Comment: How I understand there are two ways you can set it from your Screen with in useLayoutEffect with setOptions() or in your `<NavigationContainer> <Stack.Navigator> <Stack.Screen options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} />,
            headerLeft: props => <Button onPress={() => {}} title="Login" />,
          })} name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
        /></Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>`

Comment: So, do I create a function for the variable logTitle. Sorry I'm only started react-native 2 week

Comment: You don't have to, in the headerTitle you can just put a string ( "test" )

`options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
            headerTitle: "Hello",
            headerLeft: props => <Button onPress={() => {}} title="Login" />,
          })}`

But take care in headerLeft and headerRight only a function is expected.